# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/pictures/assets/small/IMG_-_WIN_20141206_09

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to upload a picture in my rails app, but it's giving me

> error:- 
>    (No route matches [GET]
>   "/system/pictures/assets/small/Image_-_WIN_20141206_09.

I don't know where I went wrong.
I try to give url, path and i also uploaded rails logo and move to `app/assets/images`

`$ curl -O` http://rubyonrails.org/image/rails.png

---

```
$ mv rails.png app/assets/images/
```

---

My git repository is at: https://github.com/sarahgupta022/book.git

---

This is my `picture.rb`

---

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :album

 belongs_to :user

 attr_accessible :caption, :description, :asset

  has_attached_file :asset, style: { 
                  large: "800x800>", medium: "300x200>", small: "260x180>",     thumb: "80x80#"
                  } , :default_url => "/app/assets/images/small/rails.png"


 validates_attachment_file_name :asset, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /gif\Z/]
 validates :asset, attachment_presence: true

def to_s

 caption? ? caption : "Picture"
   end  
 end
```

---

This is my `views/pictures/index.html.erb`

---

```
<% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
   <li>
<div class="thumbnail">
    <%= link_to image_tag(picture.asset.url(:small)),  album_picture_path(@user, @album, picture) %><br /><br />
    <div class="caption">
        <% if picture.caption? %><%= picture.caption %><br /><br /><% end %>

        <%= link_to 'View full size', album_picture_path(@user, @album, picture) %>

        <% if can_edit_picture?(picture) %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_album_picture_path(@album, picture) %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", album_picture_path(@album, picture), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

**Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this:

```
:default_url => "/app/assets/images/small/rails.png"
```

to this:

```
:default_url => "images/:style/rails.png"
```